# Помогите разобраться со ссылка в Java

Tags: java, ссылки, объекты

Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться с ссылками в java.

Вот хороший пример:

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 7;
        String s = "asd";
        Person p = new Person("bb1", 6);
        method1(a);
        method2(s);
        method3(p);
        System.out.println(a); //7 - это потому что не было присваивания, верно?
        System.out.println(s); //asd - тут тоже вроде бы понятно
        System.out.println(p); //qwerty - а вот тут - почему только тут содержимое объекта меняется?
    }

    public static void method1(int a) {
        ++a;
        a++;
    }

    public static void method2(String s) {
        s = "bfr";
    }

    public static void method3(Person p) {
        p.setName("qwerty");
    }
}

public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + age;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все параметры метода передаются в джаве по значению.

1) передавая примитив в метод, значение просто копируется

```
 public static void method1(int a) {
    ++a;
    a++;
}
```

т.е. внутри метода создается **локальная** переменная с именем а, и ее изменение никак не влияет на состояние переменой а в методе main

2) Передавая в метод параметр ссылочного типа, вы передаете копию указателя.

```
public static void method2(String s) {
    s = "bfr";
}
```

т.е. s - это какое-то значение 0xA12s, оно указывает на обьект в памяти "asd", и когда вы передаете s в метода, копируется само значение указателя  0xA12s. Т.е. по факту тоже самое что с int. Т.е. от того, что вы измените ссылку s на 0x12abc ничего не изменится, потому что это внутри метода мейн ссылка останется прежней.

3) Когда вы передаете Person, опять же тупо копируются ссылка на этот обьект.

```
    public static void method3(Person p) {
    p.setName("qwerty");
}
```

Т.е. внутри main p=0x123 -> (какая-то область в памяти) и
внутри method3   p=0x123 -> (та же область в памяти)

когда вы вызываете сеттер идет разименование ссылки, вызывается метод на том обьекте, ссылку на который вы передали. И меняется его значение в пямяти, т.е.

```
до   : p=0x123 -> ("bb1", 6) 
после: p=0x123 -> ("qwerty", 6)
```

т.е. когда метод закончился указатель все еще смотрит на туже область в памяти только теперь, там в поле имя, вместо ссылки на бб1 ссылка на кверти.

Рекоммендую включить гугл транслейт и обратиться к похожим вопросам:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас имеется некоторый метод, как, например, этот

```
public static void method2(String parameter) {
    parameter = "bfr";
}
```

И вы его вызываете как

```
String argument = "asd";
method2( argument);
```

то параметр метода инициализируется аргументом, указанным при вызове. То есть это можно представить себе следующим образом

```
public static void method2( /*String parameter*/) {
    String parameter = argument;
    parameter = "bfr";
}
```

Как видно, в методе меняется значение переменной `parameter`. Сначала ей присваивается значение переменной `argument`, а затем новое значение строкового литерала `"bfr"`

Сама исходная переменная `argument` не изменилась. Ей ничего не было присвоено.

Что касается этого метода

```
public static void method3(Person p) {
    p.setName("qwerty");
}
```

то здесь также параметр с именем `p` получил копию значения своего аргумента. Сам аргумент в методе не меняется. Но так как после вызова функции параметр, получивший значение аргумента, указывает на тот же самый объект, что и аргумент, то с его помощью можно изменить адресуемый объект.

То есть в этом методе изменяется не аргумент, а объект, на который ссылается аргумент, так как параметр получает ту же самую ссылку на объект.

Answer (score 0):

`int` - примитивный тип, а вот s уже такой же экземпляр класса `String`, как и p экземпляр класса `Person` (именно поэтому **S**tring пишется с большой буквы) и в метод передается ссылка на ячейку памяти.

Класс String по сути массив символов.

Но у Stringa есть несколько ньюансов в инициализации. Так например:

```
s1='string';
s2='string';
s1==s2; // true
```